# How to get Uint8List from storage downloadURL?

Tags: flutter

I uploaded images and videos in `FirebaseStorage` and also have downloadURLs of them. But I don't know how to get `Uint8List` data from them. Does anyone know how to get the `Uint8List` data from storage items???

Answer (score 0):

With those links you can actually use widgets to display the images or videos without any additional code.

But if you want to retrieve an `Uint8List` object for your code then you need this code on an asynchronous method.

```dart
    Uint8List bytes =
        (await NetworkAssetBundle(Uri.parse(imageUrl)).load(imageUrl))
            .buffer
            .asUint8List();
```